# Output one of numerous tables onto a range, based on a sequence of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to populate the range in **'Today's Matchups!'$AD$4:$AK$8** based on the values generated by four functions I employ in each cell in 'Today's Matchups!'$AL$4:$AO$4.

Based on the sequence generated by the functions that range, I would like it to output a table that corresponds to that sequence of four values from **'Battle Strategy Scenarios'** worksheet onto Today's Matchups!'$AD$4:$AK$8. But if the sequence doesn't correspond to a table in 'Battle Strategy Scenarios', then I would like the range in 'Today's Matchups!' to *remain blank*.

Please see:
1)link to a copy of the google sheets document[link to a copy of the google sheets document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NXa8ZnvuTz9ArQvzQrzMPt-fEBUnAoDpW6sRq5TWM1k/edit#gid=2117997643)
2) [Match of a sequence to a Battle Strategy Scenarios table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jyg7_Mr3TOQFk6tu2IuhvOp2wFLcbQwM4s1nNfDehy0/edit#gid=0) (according to both their actual ranges and my named ranges):

I've been racking my brain...tried everything from ARRAYFORMULA with IF/SWITCH to MAP and LAMBDA functions, but I can't seem to get it right. I left some of my work there.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=if(AO4=2,indirect("HARDw1UNBEATABLE"&AL4&AM4),
 if((AO4=1)*(AN4=3),indirect("MAXPOINTS"&AL4&AM4),
 if((AO4=1)*(AN4=2),indirect("HARD"&AL4&AM4,))))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, that seems to work perfectly and is elegant in its simplicity haha. I just tweaked the end by adding:
IFERROR(1/0))))